# I want to Create a Crystal Report of Paid Sales Invoices

Tags: crystal-reports-2016, crystal-reports-formulas

When a Sales invoice is paid it is matched against the receipt.
A Sales invoice can also be matched against a credit note but there is no distinguishing flag.
I want the final report to only show the Paid invoices.
I am currently Grouping by Customer, then Matching Letter, then document, so at this level you can see if the match is with a receipt or with credit notes.
I output the Group footer of the document giving me a list of documents, which for a customer payment will start with the Receipt, followed by one or more invoices totaling the value of the receipt:

GF4 Customer A  Match BC    REC101009798                    GBP240.00
GF4 Customer A  Match BC    INV101059389        ‘new field’ GBP120.00
GF4 Customer A  Match BC    INV101059390        ‘new field’ GBP120.00

If the matching is as a result of a customer payment, the Receipt will always be on the first line in the group output.

How do I create a ’new field’ on the Invoice lines that will say “Paid” , it doesn’t matter if the new field also appears on the Receipt line?

I have tried to use a formula on the group footer referencing the document type but of course when the document type changes, so does the result of the formula.
Having a success on the first line I have been concentrating on trying to copy the result on to the successive lines so thought a fresh pair of eyes might help.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Pals, I have solved this with a colleague.
We revised the formula on the Group Footer. First we created a formula that assigned a 1 to a Receipt and 0 to all other docments: IF {GACCDUDATE.TYP_0} = "REC01" THEN 1 ELSE 0. Next we created a SUM formula: IF Sum({@rowIsPaid}, {GACCENTRYD.MTC_0}) > 0 THEN "Paid"
and put this on the Group footer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Subreport. You can pass inv no or doc type to subreport and get status . Put subreport in invoice line.